# Is it possible to add multiple SAS macro values in to single macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

For instance, I have 2 macro variables ....

```
%let A = ('a','b','c');
%let B = ('d','e','f');
```

I'm trying to create a new macro variable from above 2 macro variables..

```
%let c = ('a','b','c','d','e','f');

I tried %let c = (&A,&B);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the compress() function within a %SYSFUNC to remove the parentheses from A and B...

You need to use %( and %) to represent the parentheses and prevent them from being interpreted as the closure of the %SYSFUNC.

```
%LET A = ('a','b','c') ;
%LET B = ('d','e','f') ;

%LET A2 = %SYSFUNC(compress(&A,%(%))) ;
%LET B2 = %SYSFUNC(compress(&B,%(%))) ;

%LET C = (&A2,&B2) ;

/* or all in one... */
%LET C = (%SYSFUNC(compress(&A,%(%))),%SYSFUNC(compress(&B,%(%)))) ;

%PUT &C ;

Macro variable C resolves to ('a','b','c','d','e','f')
```

Incidentally, if you intend on using &C in an in() condition, it will work as-is, i.e.

```
%LET A = ('a','b','c') ;
%LET B = ('d','e','f') ;
%LET C = (&A,&B) ;

data test ;
  letter = 'd' ;
  exist = letter in &C ; /* resolves to (('a','b','c'),('d','e','f')) */
run ;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are the one who is defining A and B, you could just remove the brackets when defining the two variables.

```
%let A = 'a','b','c';
%let B = 'd','e','f';
%let C = (&A,&B);
%PUT &C ;
```

Result from log - ('a','b','c','d','e','f')

Joe... isn't this simpler?

Comment: Keni, I'm not sure what the comment to me is.  That's nearly identical to what I said - define them without the brackets.  The only difference is I wouldn't define C with brackets either, to make it more flexible.

Comment: Yes my response is similar to yours in how we manipulated the variables A and B. I assumed that manipulating C in a similar way gives the result the OP was looking for. This was one of my first responses on SO so apologies about the confusion. I am getting to understand SO style in time. Trying to keep up with you is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

While it's possible to combine them as Chris J shows, the better answer is not to store them this way.  If you're storing them with parentheses because you will use them later in a situation where parentheses are needed, simply provide them then.

```
%let A = 'a','b','c';
%let B = 'd','e','f';
%let C = &a,&b;

data want;
set have;
if a in (&a) or b in (&b) or c in (&c) then do;
output;
end;
run;
```

Much simpler code that way.